# Iterating over multiple lists using purrr::map

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, purrr, magrittr

Below is my data

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
lst <- unique(gapminder$continent)
ylst = c(2007, 1952)
map2_dfr(lst,ylst, ~gapminder %>% filter(continent == .x & year == .y) %>% 
          arrange(desc(gdpPercap))
        %>% slice(1) %>% select(continent, country,gdpPercap,year))
```

The data is the gapminder data from the R library 'gapminder'.

I want to find the country with the highest gdpPercap for each year for each continent using purrr.

However this code is giving me the error that the lengths of my two lists are not the same
What is the map syntax to iterate over two lists, when the lengths are not the same? And how should I use that to fix the code and achieve my objective?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with the code as both have the same length

Comment: I've edited the length of the second list now

Comment: What do you want to happen when the two lists are not the same length?

Comment: You want the combination of each continent with each year? so the cross product of the two lists?

Comment: yes exactly. Each continent with 2007 and each continent with 1952.

Comment: `purrr::cross2(lst, ylst)` will give you the cartesian product as a list, so you can map over that output.

Comment: @Brian how do you filter for the cartesian product list. I have created a cross product list-  z =cross2(lst, ylst).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by grouping and nesting:

```
gapminder %>% 
  filter(year %in% ylst) %>% 
  group_by(continent, year) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data=map(data, ~top_n(., 1, gdpPercap))) %>% 
  unnest(c(data)) %>% 
  select(continent, country,gdpPercap,year)
```